# Prove that for complex numbers you can apply the formula for the difference of squares

Tags: complex

a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b) a in R, b in C

Comment: I think you wanted to ask this on [math.SE]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are in the wrong forum, but here is a way to "show" what you want in Mathematica:

```
b = x + I y;
Block[{Equal = Inactive[Equal]},
 Expand /@ (a^2 - b^2 == (a - b) (a + b))
]

(* a^2-x^2-2 I x y+y^2 == a^2-x^2-2 I x y+y^2 *)
```